How should I binerize my EEGs and use the Lempel-Ziv function on epochs or channels, or segments?
I have some EEG signal which are loaded in MATLAB like segmentschannelsepochs (e.g. 10001957). Idk how should I extract complexity features like lempel-ziv. Idk how should I binerized my EEGs and using LZ function on epochs or channels or segments?
(I already had the lempel-ziv function)
many thanks in advance
Idk the results of Lempel-ziv for EEG MDD shoulg be in what interval
